# Blank admin screens after upgrading Prestashop from 1.7.4 to 1.7.6

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I've upgraded my site's Prestashop version from 1.7.4 to 1.7.6. But after the update, I can't see data in the back office. I can log in without any issues. I can also see the dashboard as it should appear. But when I goto Advance Parameters->Information, it's blank. I'm not able to see any options related to it. I can only see sidebar and headers of admin, but no options for Information. Because of that, my site is now in maintenance mode, and I can't pull out my site from it. (Maintenance mode should be enabled if I want to upgrade Prestashop version)

This issue is with many functions in BackOffice like modules, themes, performance, etc. So please help me with that. Please see this screenshot https://prnt.sc/olbpus

Comment: Did you check your logs? Is the debug mode enabled in your store? If not go to Advanced Parameters -> Performance if it works or to the config folder in the root and set define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true); to true. At least you will see where the ploblem come from

Comment: Yes, I've enabled the DEBUG mode and there were no errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your shop out of maintenance by setting the PS_SHOP_ENABLE to 1 in the ps_configuration table of your database.

As for the backoffice hard to say without any error showing.
If no debug error, check your server logs (apache/nginx depending on what you use).

Answer (score 0):

after upragding you need to remove cache from prestashop .
clear this folder cache/smarty/compile and this cache/smarty/cache from your directory and then remove caches from  /var/cache/ .
it's maybe help you!